# Problem when trying to assign a value into a member of a typedef stuct variable

Tags: c, gcc

I have declared a typedef structure like that:

```
typedef struct {
    u8  member_a;
    u32 member_d;
    u32 member_c;
    u16 member_d;
} __attribute__((packed)) fourmembers;
```

Then, I have created a variable named "limp" which is of type "fourmembers":

```
fourmembers limp;
```

Following, I've tried to assign a value to "member_a" member of the "fourmembers" variable like that:

```
limp.member_a = 0x20;
```

the result is that GCC gave the following error:

```
error: 'fourmembers' has no member named 'member_a'
```

Could anyone please advise me on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't advice you since the code appears to be correct, but you haven't supplied a complete example. On the other hand, I would strongly advice you not to use the `packed` attribute. If you rearrange the struct so that you place the big variables near the beginning and the small towards the end, you will have minimal amount of padding.

Comment: probably a typo u32 member_d; should be u32 member_b;

Comment: @Lindydancer: The code, as posted, produces this error - just not as the first error

Comment: What are `u8`, `u32`, and `u16`? :)

Comment: If you really require members with a specific width (i.e. 8-, 16-, or 32-bits) then you should consider using `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and friends from [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h)

Answer (score 3):

You have two member variables called `member_d`.  That's probably not helping matters.

Once I alter that, I can get a short code snippet to compile without problems.  So if this doesn't fix your problem, you'll need to post a small, complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is not looking at the *first* compiler error - the one that tells you why the compiler couldn't create the `fourmembers` struct. This error would be that `u8` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, since you asked for advice on what you're doing wrong:

1. Using nonstandard names for fixed-size types instead of the standard names `uint8_t` `uint16_t` etc. This is actually the source of your compile error.
2. Using `__attribute__((packed))`. Forget you ever learned about it. It's always wrong.
3. Not giving us a sufficiently complete code fragment to determine the cause of the error.